# VS2015 Extensibility - How to check for pending Edit and Continue changes?

Tags: c#, roslyn, vsx

I'm writing a Visual Studio extension (VSPackage). Given an IMethodSymbol or a MethodDeclarationSyntax, for instance, how can I ask Visual Studio whether the given method contains pending Edit and Continue changes that have not been applied yet?

Comment: It looks like the relevant APIs are all internal. http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Features/EditAndContinue/EditSession.cs